# Entity Framework: how to solve table in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance, poco

I'm testing the following scenario (code below): create a shopping mall, with shops, with cashiers, with cash desks and persons operating it.

So I've created the following classes

- Table **Mall**
- Table **Shop**
- Table **CashDesk**
- Table **Person**

Basic classes with an ID and a name.

Then I need a derived class from `Person` being `PersonCashier` or `PersonCustomer`.

Since everything is related, I need to create intersection tables for the many to many scenarios.

I've created the following intersection tables:

- The Mall contains shops: **MallShop**
- The shop contains CashDesks: **MallShopCashDesk**
- And the CashDesk containing cashiers: **MallShopCashDeskPersonCashier**

This just doesnt feel right. Can anyone help me out on a best practice

```
public class Mall
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int NumberOfShopSpaces { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CashDesk
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
public class PersonCashier : Person
{
    [Required]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

These are the base classes. How should i add a shop to a mall, a cashdesk to a shop, and a cashier to a cashdesk? (i've tried alot but posting the code would make the question look like spaghetti)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Mall
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int NumberOfShopSpaces { get; set; }

    List<Shop> CurrentShops { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CashDesk> CashDesks { get;set; }
}
```

I added the list of shops to the Mall class and CashDesks to Shops. This gives you a list of shops in the mall, and a list of cashdesks in each shop and you can follow this method for everything else you need.

If you have a database, you will have a Mall table and a Shop table.

The Shop table can have a Foreign Key to the Mall table, that's how you link them and this will work with the class structure at the top.

Or, you can have another table called MallShops where you have 2 fields, one being the MallID, the other the ShopID. This is called a Link table.

Both approaches will work with the second allowing a more complex structure with lots of Malls linked to Lots of Shops.

I would start with the database structure first, make sure you cover all you need, then you can do the classes etc in a way that makes sense. If you use something like EntityFramework then it will create all the classes for you once your database structure is ready.

Answer (score 1):

If this is code first then EF will make the relationship tables for you. You just need to add the relationships in your classes.

Exactly what they should be is not clear from your description because it depends on what relationships you want; if you want a many-many between PersonCashier and CashDesk it would be like this:

```
public class CashDesk
{
    public List<PersonCashier> Cashiers { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCashier : Person
{
    public List<CashDesk> CashDesks { get; set; }
}
```

(not showing all the fields for brevity)